# How to fix this dev/sda1 contains a file system with error ,check forced . /60.3%

Tags: bash, filesystem, disk, boot-repair, input-devices

[image]

```
Disk /dev/sda1 contain file system with error
Run fsck manually 
Intrafarms not open
Boot error
```

Comment: Please can you give details of what caused this message to appear - is it at start up or does something trigger it? Please also give details of your Ubuntu version and hardware setup. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and a screenshot of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window... make the window large enough to capture all of the data in the screenshot. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: The image display shows /dev/sdb1, but your text indicates /dev/sda1. Which is it? Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l`.